# Let $A=(a_{ij})_{4 \times 4}$ is a matrix with all it's cofactor $A_{ij}=s \ \forall \ 1 \le i,j \le 4$ .That enough to claim $\text{rank} \ A=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a &b &c \\ d&e &f \\ g&h&k \end{bmatrix}$. And  $\text{adj} \ A=\begin{bmatrix} s&s&s\\s&s&s \\ s&s&s \end{bmatrix}$, prove that $s=0$

My attempt:

Because  $A \ . \text{adj} \ A=|A|E $  So that $\begin{bmatrix}s(a+b+c) &s(a+b+c) & s(a+b+c) \\ s(d+e+f) & s(d+e+f) & s(d+e+f) \\ s(g+h+k) & s(g+h+k) & s(g+h+k)  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} |A| & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &|A| &0 \\ 0 &0 & |A|\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore, as a result we get: $\begin{cases}s(a+b+c)=0 \\ s(d+e+f)=0 \\ s(g+h+k)=0 \end{cases}$.

If $s=0$ we have done !, else $a+b+c=0, \ d+e+f=0$ and $g+h+k=0$

And we have :

$\begin{cases}ae-bd=s \\ bf-ec=s\\ dc-af=s \\ ch-bk=s \\ ak-gc=s\\ ah-bg=s\\ ek-hf=s\\ gf-dk=s\\ dh-ge=s\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} ak-gc=s \\ ah-bg=s \end{cases}\Rightarrow a(h+k)-g(b+c)=2s \Rightarrow a(-g)-g(-a)=2s $

i.e $s=0$, not in accordance with condition, so that $s=0$.

So my question is:

**Let $(a_{ij})_{4 \times 4}$ is a matrix of order $4$ with all it's cofactor $A_{ij}=s \ \forall \ 1 \le i,j \le 4$ .That enough to claim $\text{rank} \ A=1$?**

Comment: It is not clear what is the relation between your title and your body (I see only square matrices of size $3$). In any case the answer to the question of the title is: no, $A$ might have rank $0$, in case $s=0$.

Comment: Do you by any chance mean by $A_{i,j}$ something else than the $i,j$ _entry_ of $A$. Maybe a cofactor of $A$ at position $i,j$?

Comment: yes, cofactor, i'm sorry, edited.

Comment: For your matrix multiplication to work, you probably meant to say that "adj $A$" was the *signed* cofactor matrix of $A$, for the sake of precision.  Also, how can we hope to conclude rank $A = 1$ when the zero matrix satisfies the condition in **bold** at the end of your post?

Comment: @hardmath according to [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), cofactors are already signed minors. And the reasoning that $s=0$ is wrong, exactly because the proper signs are forgotten.

Comment: @Road Human I have answered, but I must agree with the vote to close because it is unclear what you were asking. I think you _might_ have wanted to say "Hey, (I think) I can prove for a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ that is all cofactors are equal, then the cofactors must be zero and $A$ must have rank${}\leq1$; now is the same still true for $n=4$?". (If that is what you wanted to say, you have a mighty unclear way of doing so.) Unfortunately, your proof for $n=3$ is wrong, and so is the claim.

Comment: Related at any rate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892039/is-adjoint-of-singular-matrix-singular-what-would-be-its-rank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the classification in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1198454/18880) (and in the answers linked from there) the rank of the adjugate matrix (or matrix of cofactors) of an $n\times n$ matrix$~A$ is $n$ if $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}\rk A=n$; it is$~1$ if $\rk A=n-1$, and it is$~0$ is $\rk A<n-1$. Now if all entries of the adjugate matrix have the same value$~s$, one can conclude that one of the following is the case:

- $\rk A=n-1$ and $s\neq0$
- $\rk A<n-1$ and $s=0$
- $n\leq 1$

In your case $n=3$, so the last possibility does not apply, and you can only conclude that $A$ is singular.

In fact your statement (and its purported proof) are wrong, since for *any* $a,b,c,d$ one has
$$\def\adj{\operatorname{adj}}
  \adj\pmatrix{a&b&-a-b\\c&d&-c-d\\-a-c&-b-d&a+b+c+d}=\pmatrix{s&s&s\\s&s&s\\s&s&s}
\quad\text{where $s=ad-bc$.}
$$
Here the original matrix $A$ has rank$~2$ whenever $s\neq0$.

The error in your reasoning is that you forgot to put in the proper signs for the cofactors.