# Finding an explicit eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over a field and let $\operatorname{adj}(A)$
denote its classical adjoint. Suppose all column sums of $A$ are zero so that $A$ is singular.

[If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n-1$, the adjoint is nonzero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1198454/1551) Hence any nonzero column of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ provides an explicit (right) eigenvector of $A$ in the null space because $A\operatorname{adj}(A)=0$.

Unfortunately, if $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le n-2$, the adjoint is identically zero so this fails to yield an eigenvector. Here is the question:

> Is there a way to modify the above to get an explicit eigenvector in the null space when $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le n-2$?

(What is desired is a formula rather than an algorithm.)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda Id)$. Since $\det(A)=0$ then $p(\lambda)=\lambda^kq(\lambda)$ such that $q(0)\neq 0$.

Notice that $q(A)\neq 0$, because $A$ is not invertible and $q(0)\neq 0$.

If $Aq(A)=0$ then there exists a non null column of $q(A)$ in the kernel of $A$.

If $Aq(A)\neq 0$ and $A^2q(A)=0$ then there exists a non null column of $Aq(A)$ in the kernel of $A$.

We can repeat the argument until we find some $s$ such that $A^{s-1}q(A)\neq 0$ and $A^{s}q(A)= 0$ (there exists such $s$ because $A^{k}q(A)= 0$) then there exists a non null column of $A^{s-1}q(A)$ in the kernel of $A$.

OBS: Notice that if $rank(A)=n-1$ then $Adj(A)=-q(A)$.

Comment: If $Aq(A)\neq 0$ and $A^2  q(A)=0$ then a non-null column of $Aq(A)$ is in the kernel of $A$.

Comment: @SungjinKim Thanks for spotting this mistake, when I wrote it back then I didn't notice it