# Maximizing the Nullity of a Symbolic Gram Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, control-theory

I have a symbolic gram matrix, that is, a matrix $AA^T$ with some entries being variables. I would like to find a solution for my variables which maximizes the nullity of this matrix, or equivalently, maximizes the number of eigenvalues which are 0. Initially I thought to simply solve for when the determinant is 0, however if such a solution exists, then it only tells me that the multiplicity of the zero-valued eigenvalues is at least 1. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to do this computation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful to you, but anyway.

By [rank- nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), we have:

> $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \quad \quad \operatorname{rank}\, (M) + \operatorname{null}\, (M) =n, $

where $n$ is the number of columns of $M$.

In order to maximize $\operatorname{null}\, (M)=n-1$, we need to have $\operatorname{rank}\,(M) = 1$.

---

Now, if $M = AA^T$, then if $\operatorname{rank}\, (A) = 1$, it follows that  $\operatorname{rank}\, (M) = 1$. So, try to create a matrix $A$ with $\operatorname{rank}\, (A) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just one idea: As you surely know the rank and the nullity of a matrix are related through $\mbox{rank}(B)+\mbox{null}(B)=\mbox{dim}(B)=n$ (let me name $B=AA^T$). If the matrix $B$ has a rank $r$, there exists at least one minor (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29) $r\times r$ different from zero. Fiting the parameters such that $\mbox{det}[B]=0$ will ensure the existence of at least one eigenvalue equal to zero. Then, you can continue making zero the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minors. If you can make all of them equal to zero, then the matrix sill have at least two zero eigenvales. You can continue this iterative procedure.

For demonstrating that all $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ are equal to zero there is a shortcut, based on the study of the adjoint matrix. As it is explained in [Is adjoint of singular matrix singular? What would be its rank?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892039/is-adjoint-of-singular-matrix-singular-what-would-be-its-rank) you have three posibilities for the rank of the adjoint matrix:
$$\mbox{rank}[\mbox{Adj}(B)]=0\quad if\quad\mbox{rank}[B]\le n-2\\
\mbox{rank}[\mbox{Adj}(B)]=1\quad if\quad\mbox{rank}[B]= n-1\\
\mbox{rank}[\mbox{Adj}(B)]=n\quad if\quad\mbox{rank}[B]=n$$

Comment: Thanks @seoanes, I think this is a good idea. I found a paper or two from control theory which are relating to this so called, "Rank Minimization Problem" and implementable algorithms to finding a solution which gives the minimal rank with high probability. One such algorithm is called "OptSpace" but would be too much to describe here. I like your idea though and may try to implement it also.