# Adjoint of a one-by-one zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Our lecturer defined the adjoint of a one-by-one matrix $A \in M_{1}(F)$ to be $\text{adj} (A) = [1]$. She did not give a specific case when $A=[0]$. So based on that definition, $\text{adj}([0]) =[1]$ and so  $\text{adj}([0])$ is nonsingular. But $\text{adj}(A)$ is nonsingular if and only if $A$ is nonsingular. And $A$ in this particular case is singular. So how should one define $\text{adj}([0])$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is it isn't true that adj(A) is non-singular iff A is non-singular. In fact, you've found the only counterexample. For more information, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892039/is-adjoint-of-singular-matrix-singular-what-would-be-its-rank).

Edit: Adj([0]) does equal [1].

Comment: I see. In our lecture, it was mentioned that $\text{adj}(A)$ is nonsingular iff $A$ is nonsingular, and no conditions were given for the matrix $A$. Does this mean that the adjoint of $[0]$ is indeed $[1]$?

Comment: Yes, it does. I should have made that clear in my original answer