# If $AB-BA=A_{*} $, then $A_{*} ^2=O_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) $. If $AB-BA=A_{*} $, then $A_{*} ^2=O_n$.
So far, I have considered the cases when $rank(A) \le n-2$ and $rank(A) =n-1$ and in both of them I obtained the conclusion. My problem is that I don't know what to do if $rank A=n$.

Comment: If $A_*$ is meant to be the conjugate transpose of $A$, it would be better to say so and/or to use the more standard notation $A^*$.

Comment: $A_{*} $ is the adjugate matrix of $A$ i.e. $A\cdot A_{*} =\det A \cdot I_n$

Answer (score 2):

$[A,B]=\operatorname{adj}(A)$ commutes with $A$. Hence it is nilpotent, by Jacobson's lemma. Now the result follows, because [the rank of every singular adjugate matix is at most $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1198454) and every nilpotent matrix of rank $\le1$ must square to zero.