# Prove that rank of Adj A is 0,1 or n always

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question is from a masters entrance for which I am preparing.

> Let $n\geq 2$ and A be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries. Let Adj A denote the adjoint of A, ie the (i,j) - th entry of Adj A is the (j,i) - th cofactor of A. Then show that the rank of Adj A is 0,1,n.

If  A= 0 matrix then Adj A =0 matrix.

If A is invertible then rank A = rank adj A = n.

If rank is 1 and A is 2$\times$ 2 matrix and if rank A is 1,2 and A is $3
\times 3$ matrix, then I have verified that the rank of AdjA will be 1 but I am unable to generalize it.

Can you shed some light on how to argue that?

Comment: The Wikipedia page [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) explains that if $A$ has full rank (rank is $n$), then $\mathrm{Adj}A$ has full rank as well. If $A$ has rank $n-1$, then $\mathrm{Adj}A$ has rank 1. And if the rank of $A$ is anything else (so $n-2, n-3, \ldots, 1, 0$), then $\mathrm{Adj}A$ will be the zero matrix.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892039/is-adjoint-of-singular-matrix-singular-what-would-be-its-rank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following three cases:

1. If $A$ has rank less than or equal to $n - 2$ then any $n - 1$ columns of $A$ are linearly dependent and in particular, any $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix of $A$ has linearly dependent columns and so zero determinant. This implies that $\operatorname{adj}(A) = 0$ and so $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}(A)) = 0$.
2. If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n - 1$ then the identity $A \cdot \operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A) \cdot I_n = 0_{n \times n}$ shows you that all the columns of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ must belong to the kernel of $A$ which is one-dimensional. Hence, $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}(A)) \leq 1$. You can in fact show that in this case $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}(A)) = 1$ but this is not needed to answer your question.
3. If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n$ then $A$ is invertible and the identity $\operatorname{adj}(A) \cdot A = \det(A) I_n$ shows you that $\operatorname{adj}(A) = \frac{1}{\det(A)} A^{-1}$ is also invertible and so has rank $n$.