# If we have $n-1$ dependent vectors of size $n$, why if we remove the $i$th element from each, they're still dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-independence

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4241655/1261066) answer to the problem of showing $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A)\in\{0,1,n\}$. In the first case we see:

> If $A$ has rank less than or equal to $n - 2$ then any $n - 1$ columns
> of $A$ are linearly dependent and in particular, any $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix of $A$ has linearly dependent columns.

I can't understand why is that correct. Is there an elementary proof to this?

Is it because for checking that those $n-1$ vectors of size $n$ are linearly dependent, we solve a $n-1$ variables and $n$ equations system and we find a non-zero answer, solving any $n-1$ variables and $n-1$ equations system from the first linear system of equations must also have a non-zero answer?

Comment: What is the size of a vector?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos By a vector of size $n$, I mean it's $n\times 1$ i.e. has $n$ entries.

Comment: And what is the size of the exponential function as a vector of the vector space of all functions form $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$? How many entries does it have?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can't find out what's the relation between this question and my question

Comment: You are correct, if a solution satisfies $n$ equations, then it must satisfies $n-1$ of those $n$ equations right?

Comment: I am trying to explain to you that, in general, there is no such thing as the size of a vector.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, you're right. I'm sorry I'm not very good at English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have some relation between the vectors, i.e. some non-trivial linear combination equating zero, the same combination will stay equal to zero when you remove a coordinate.

In other words, suppose that $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ are $n-1$ vectors in ${\mathbb R}^n$, and suppose that they are linearly dependent i.e. we have $\lambda_1v_1+\ldots+\lambda_{n-1}v_{n-1}=0$ for some numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ not all zero. If you denote by $p$ the linear projection ${\mathbb R}^n \to {\mathbb R}^{n-1}$ which removes the $i$-th coordinate, then you have

$$
0=p(0)=p(\lambda_1v_1+\ldots+\lambda_{n-1}v_{n-1})=
\lambda_1p(v_1)+\ldots+\lambda_{n-1}p(v_{n-1})
$$

so the vectors $p(v_1),p(v_2),\ldots,p(v_{n-1})$ are linearly dependent also.

Answer (score 1):

Let those $n-1$ vectors be $v_1,...,v_{n-1}$ and $v_k(j)$ denote the $j$-th entry of $v_k$, the condition indicates that there are nontrivial coefficients $c_k$ such that $\sum c_k v_k(j)=0$ simultaneously for all $j$ in $\{1,..,n\}$.

So the equation is also true if we restrict the range of $j$ from $\{1,..,n\}$ into any subset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose given any $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ submatrix
$$ \tilde{A}=(\tilde{v}_{l_1}, \tilde{v}_{l_2},\cdots, \tilde{v}_{l_{n-1}})  $$
its corresponding column is $v_{l_1}, v_{l_2},\cdots, v_{l_{n-1}}$. Since $v_{l_1}, v_{l_2},\cdots, v_{l_{n-1}}$ are linearly dependent, exists $\lambda_{l_1}, \cdots, \lambda_{l_{n-1}}\in \mathbb{F}$ s.t.
$$ \lambda_{l_1}v_{l_1}+ \cdots+ \lambda_{l_{n-1}}v_{l_{n-1}}=0.$$
Then
$$ \lambda_{l_1}\tilde{v}_{l_1}+ \cdots+ \lambda_{l_{n-1}}\tilde{v}_{l_{n-1}}=0. $$

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Excuse me, I can accept only one answer.